# java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 11029 nor current process has android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE

Tags: java, android, timezone, alarmmanager, android-permissions

I am working on an old project which sets time zone programatically, i am migrating this project to Api 28, it works without error on Kitkat device but in Api 28, SET_TIME_ZONE permission can't be granted, as i know it became system level permission and can't be available for apps.

I have added this permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

and Activity onCreate method looks like this

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 2654);
} 
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setTimeZone("Asia/Tbilisi");
```

and getting error on Api 28 or higher

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 11029 nor current process has android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE.
```

I want to keep this functionality, whats your advice what should i use instead of AlarmManager.setTimeZone() method to change system time?

Answer (score 1):

Prompt for timezone selection.if you need the user to select a specific zone,give a message with the instruction before opening setting activity to prompt the user.After selecting,you can then check if the system timezone is as expected and take whatever action.

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: I dont want to let user change time zone, thats why i set timezone to a specific city in activity.

Comment: currently,there is no method to change the time zone,the option you have is to show a dialog or something with the instructions to set the timezone you want then on clicking  the positive button,open timezone settings.When the user goes back to the app, check the timezone set by the user and block progress of the app until the user sets the timezone you want if not set.